# Return number of objects based on created date from a list of nested JSON objects

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a list of JSON objects and want to return a dictionary with the count of objects based on `created[year-month]` where `created[year-month]` is the key and `count` the value.

I tried:

```
result = {}
for record in data_in:
    if record['created'][:7] not in result:
        result[record['created'][:7]] = {"created": 0}
    result[record["created"][:7]]["created"] += 1
        
result
```

And code produces the below output:

```
{'2020-03': {'created': 1},
 '2020-04': {'created': 1},
 '2020-01': {'created': 3}}
```

But my desired out is:

```
{
  '2020-03': 1, 
  '2020-04': 1, 
  '2020-01': 3
}
```

I know I'm missing something out but can't figure out what. Can some one help refactor the code, or provide a better approach to get the desired output?

**Note**:

1. Additional imports are not allowed.

JSON file

```
data_in =   [
    {
        "package": "FLEXIBLE",
        "created": "2020-03-10T00:00:00",
        "summary": [
            {
                "period": "2019-12",
                "documents": {
                    "incomes": 63,
                    "expenses": 13
                }
            },
            {
                "period": "2020-02",
                "documents": {
                    "incomes": 45,
                    "expenses": 81
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "package": "ENTERPRISE",
        "created": "2020-04-19T00:00:00",
        "summary": [
            {
                "period": "2020-01",
                "documents": {
                    "incomes": 15,
                    "expenses": 52
                }
            },
            {
                "period": "2020-02",
                "documents": {
                    "incomes": 76,
                    "expenses": 47
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        'package': 'FLEXIBLE',
        'created': '2020-01-15T00:00:00',
        'summary': [
            {
                'period': '2020-03',
                'documents': {
                    'incomes': 39, 
                    'expenses': 48
                }
            },
            {
                'period': '2020-04', 
                'documents': {
                    'incomes': 76, 
                    'expenses': 20
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    
    {
        'package': 'INTERNAL',
        'created': '2020-01-07T00:00:00',
        'summary': [
            {
                'period': '2019-12',
                'documents': {
                    'incomes': 4, 
                    'expenses': 53
                }
            },
            {
                'period': '2020-01', 
                'documents': {
                    'incomes': 60, 
                    'expenses': 48
                }
            },
            {
                'period': '2020-02', 
                'documents': {
                    'incomes': 88, 
                    'expenses': 85
                }
            },
            {
                'period': '2020-03', 
                'documents': {
                    'incomes': 84, 
                    'expenses': 81
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        'package': 'ENTERPRISE',
        'created': '2020-01-03T00:00:00',
        'summary': [
            {
                'period': '2020-04',
                'documents': {
                    'incomes': 27, 
                    'expenses': 13
                }
            }
        ]
    }]
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the json file you're working with?

Comment: @sahasrara62 Can You hel me. I don't know how to connest created with items

Comment: You have to find out what is meant by `items` and what are they asking you about. Our guess is as good as your guess.

Comment: @Jamiu S.  The expected result is items...that's all I was told in the information above:       '''
        Return number of items per created[year-month].
        ex. {
            '2020-04': 29,
            '2020-05': 24
        }
    '''

Comment: @Jamiu S.   item this {"package": "ENTERPRISE", "created": "2020-03-19T00:00:00", "summary": []}

Comment: @Jamiu S.  this is an example, it was already in the quest. Does not necessarily correspond to the target value here is 29 and 24 and the result can be {
   "2020-01": 278887,
   "2019-12": 261704,
   "2020-03": 197715,
   "2020-02": 261694
}

Comment: @Jamiu S. item this {"package": "ENTERPRISE", "created": "2020-03-19T00:00:00", "summary": []}  so we have to Return number of {"package": "ENTERPRISE", "created": "2020-03-19T00:00:00", "summary": []} per created[year-month].

Comment: @Jamiu S. for our data we have 5 items:  {'2020-03': 1, '2020-04': 1, '2020-01': 3}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This approach will count objects in `data_in` based on `'created'` date. `record['created'][:7]` will extract `YYYY-MM` from `'created'` string

```py
new_dict = {}
for record in data_in:
    created = record['created'][:7]
    if created not in new_dict:
        new_dict[created] = 0
    new_dict[created] += 1
print(new_dict)
```

---

```
{'2020-03': 1, '2020-04': 1, '2020-01': 3}
```

Comment: Can you post json file with You are using? because I would like to cheak it's right...

Comment: I am using the data you provided.

Comment: Why You only count 'incomes' ?

Comment: I am only anticipating, it could either be `incomes`  or `expenses` but until you know exactly what you are looking for I don't think any body can help.

Comment: item this {"package": "ENTERPRISE", "created": "2020-03-19T00:00:00", "summary": []}

Comment: So you mean you want to count the total objects in `data_in` base on `"created"`?

Comment: Yes! You have right. Do You have any idea?

Comment: GOOD Thank You, I can just accept one solution :(

Comment: Now I made an edit to the answer which should work fine.

Comment: This solution is faster than previous one

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly, you can just modify your code to increment the counter directly instead of storing this value in a dictionary.

```py
result = {}
for record in data_in:
    if record['created'][:7] not in result:
        result[record['created'][:7]] = 1
    else:
        result[record["created"][:7]] += 1
```

Note that your solution assumes that the `created` date will always be in `YYYY-MM-...` format.

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes I did that but I'm not sure... I don't know what items is?

Comment: Please explain what exactly you want to count?

Comment: @sahasrara62 Do you know what we should to retur?

Comment: '''
        Return number of items per created[year-month].
        ex. {
            '2020-04': 29,
            '2020-05': 24
        }
    '''

Comment: mayby You have right but I'm not sure because this task for me and they also did't talk me what I shoud to return. So I'm searching for help.... hence my post :)

Comment: I see. Sorry, but I can't help you with solving a task when we both don't know what the task is.

Comment: @Jamiu S.  item this {"package": "ENTERPRISE", "created": "2020-03-19T00:00:00", "summary": []}